# How to define multiple routes in a single SAM template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-serverless

I've a requirement where by I need to define multiple routes in my API gateway each route doing a specific thing. I am using AWS::Serverless::Function and I thought of defining multiple "Path" under "Events" but my CFN failing with the error

Resource handler returned message: "The REST API doesn't contain any methods (Service: ApiGateway, Status Code: 400, Request ID: dfe9e452-9312-4c67-ba59-0ea7jq72cce5)"

My CFN template for AWS::Serverless::Function is below

```
MyLambdaFunction:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
  Properties:
    Description: >
      Currently does not support S3 upload event.
    Handler: index.handler
    Runtime: nodejs20.x
    FunctionName:
      !Sub
        - "${TheEnv}-${TheAppNameForResources}-get-v1"
        - TheEnv: !Ref Environment
          TheAppNameForResources: !Ref AppNameForResources
    CodeUri: .
    MemorySize: 10240
    Role: !GetAtt MyLambdaExecutionRole.Arn
    Events:
      MyDemoAPI:
        Type: Api
        Properties:
          # RestApiId:
          # Ref: MyApiGateway
          Path: /batch
          Method: GET
      MyTestAPI:
        Type: Api
        Properties:
        # RestApiId:
          # Ref: MyApiGateway
          Path: /qa
          Method: GET
    Tracing: Active
    Tags:
      AppName: !Ref AppNameForTags
      Cost: !Ref CostTagValue

MyApiGateway:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
  Properties:
    Name:
      !Sub
      - '${TheEnv}-${TheAppNameForResources}-api'
      - TheEnv: !Ref Environment
        TheAppNameForResources: !Ref AppNameForResources
        TheBucketRegion: !Ref AWS::Region
    StageName: test
    TracingEnabled: true
    OpenApiVersion: 3.0.2
    Cors:
      AllowHeaders: "'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token'"
      AllowMethods: "'*'"
      AllowOrigin: "'*'"
```

I commented out the reference to RestApiId hoping that I could define multiple routes in a single AWS::Serverless::Function block.

I am not sure what went wrong here. My questions

1. Should I necessarily define AWS::Serverless::Api block?
2. Can I define multiple routes in a single AWS::Serverless::Function block?
3. When exactly I need AWS::Serverless::Api block if I could achieve that with AWS::Serverless::Function?

Any help much appreciated.